# How to get 12.04 native theme after upgrade from 10.04 with /home unformated

Tags: 12.04, gnome, 10.04

I had 10.04 with /home on its own partition. I then freshly installed 12.04 while retaining /home. The whole process went perfectly well.

But my desktop still retains a gnome-like look. I know it has something to do with a .gnome* folder with gnome settings.

[image]

Can anyone help me fix this to have the 12.04 native look?

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Settings > Appearance and change the Theme. Simple.

Screenshot:
[image]
<sub>(source: [nuigalway.ie](https://compsoc.nuigalway.ie/~paulk/gedit_correct.png))</sub>